# Empty row of excel is missing in apache poi workbook sheet

Tags: javafx, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I'm working on javafx project where i need to show excel sheets on TableView for this i'm using

> org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook

My code for reading excel file is as follows

```
public Workbook getCommonWorkBook(File file) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        return workbook;
}
```

my excel sheet is looks like :

[image: excel file snnipt]

when i iterate rows of workbook sheet, i didn't get empty row (second indexed row)
Code of iterating row is here :

```
Workbook workbook = COMMON_SERVICE.getCommonWorkBook(file);
                if (workbook != null) {
                    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
                    if (sheet != null) {
                        List<List<String>> rowList = new ArrayList();
                        sheet.rowIterator().forEachRemaining(r ->
                            System.out.println("r   :  " + r.toString()));
```

Output

> r   :  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow@2a
>
> r   :  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow@2a

[image]

I need to show empty row in table view as well please assist me.

Comment: Did you read [the JavaDoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#rowIterator--)? It states undefined rows are left out. The editor you're using does not seem to define empty rows which is perfectly fine...

Comment: See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator -> "Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells"